# User MATLAB's webread without plain text password

Tags: matlab, authentication, httpwebrequest

I have a webapi that uses AD's logins for authentication. If I want to access that webapi with MATLAB using `webread`, I can do that but apparently I have to place in plain text my username and password into the `weboptions`

```
options = weboptions;
options.Username = 'foo';
options.Password = 'SuperSecurePW';
data = webread('url', options)
```

That is terrible, I don't want to place my PWD in plain text. Is there a possibility to use the currect Windows-Login as authentication?

Comment: Not sure if MATLAB is the right tool if you are worried about cybersecurity :D

Comment: I hate MATLAB, believe me, but unfortunately, that is not a variable I'm allowed to change.

Comment: I just don't think you can do it, not using `weboptions` at least.... Good luck